# How to delete rows that have a cell that has a special symbol?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete rows that have cells containing ®.

```
Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = "*®*"
Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = "®"
```

I have also tried setting condition_ranges and conditions instead - I have not been able to get anything to work in regard to the special character.

```
Sub Remove()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 1000
   For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
   If Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = "BLK" Then
       Rows(iCntr).Delete
   ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = "WHI" Then
       Rows(iCntr).Delete
   ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 7).Value = "*®*" Then
       Rows(iCntr).Delete

 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

The code works just fine for the "BLK" and "WHI" but nothing is taken out using the "*®*".  There are no error messages it just does not modify the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Like`:

```
ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 7).Value Like "*®*" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The question could be translated to *"How to check whether a string contains a specific substring"*, because once this part is resolved, then the corresponding cell could be deleted.

[InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) is a function, that compares two strings, returning the position of the second one within the first one. If the second one is not found in the first one, then `0` is returned. With some fantasy, this could be used to see whether the (R) is present:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print ThePresenceOfR("kt®b")
    Debug.Print ThePresenceOfR("tzv")
End Sub

Function ThePresenceOfR(str As String) As Boolean
    ThePresenceOfR = InStr(1, str, "®")
End Function
```

Or as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486117/5448626), `kt®b Like "*®*"` would deliver the same results.